# Writing plot increments in Latex font?

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

Is there a way to type the increments on the x and y axes in Latex font, instead of just Arial?

Likewise, the legend?

Comment: Do you want to change latex font?

Comment: Well. The increment numbers are in Arial font. And I want it to be in the latex font.

Answer (score 1):

To change the font of the axis labels, in the preamble of your program, you can 
do so by editing the `rc` parameters:

```
import matplotlib

font = {'fontname' : 'serif',
        'weight' : 'bold',
        'size'   : 22}

matplotlib.rc('font', **font)
```

Now your font labels are set accordingly. You can customise the fonts accordingly.